# excel-vba function to filter an array and return an array

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function to filter a 2-d array.

It works. But I am not sure if the following mechanism is a sensible concept.

The idea is:

1. loop over the input array which is received as `input_arr(y,x)`
2. store the values in `temp_arr(x,y)`, since in order to resize the y-dimension it
   needs to be last dimension, so I have to transpose the values as I
   store them
3. once the loop is done, transpose `temp_arr(x,y)` which
   becomes the return value

   ```
   Public Function filter_arr(input_arr As Variant, col_index As Long, filter_value As Variant) As Variant

    'the input_arr might be indexed starting from 0 or 1
    Dim n1 As Long, n2 As Long
    n1 = LBound(input_arr, 2)
    n2 = UBound(input_arr, 2)

    Dim temp_arr() As Variant
    Dim y As Long, x As Long, count As Long
    count = 0

    If (LBound(input_arr, 1) = 0) Then
     For y = LBound(input_arr, 1) To UBound(input_arr, 1)
      If (input_arr(y, col_index) = filter_value) Then

       ReDim Preserve temp_arr(n1 To n2, 0 To count)
       For x = n1 To n2
        temp_arr(x, count) = input_arr(y, x)
       Next x
       count = count + 1

     End If
    Next y

    Else

    'if LBound(input_arr, 1) = 1
    For y = LBound(input_arr, 1) To UBound(input_arr, 1)

     If (input_arr(y, col_index) = filter_value) Then

      count = count + 1
      ReDim Preserve temp_arr(n1 To n2, 1 To count)
      For x = n1 To n2
       temp_arr(x, count) = input_arr(y, x)
      Next x

      End If
     Next y

    End If

    filter_arr = Application.Transpose(temp_arr)

   End Function
   ```

Edit: adding some context

Imagine that I have a `ws` in an `.xlam` file that contains product information which I've added as an add-in.

I have a function like `=getProductData()` which returns an array containing that data

So excel has a `SORT` function which works great with this kind of thing. I can do `=SORT(getProductData(), 2, 1)` to return my product data sorted by the 2nd column

But excel's `FILTER` function needs me to specify the data itself as its second parameter, not just its index, like in `SORT`

I can use `INDEX` to do something like `=SORT(FILTER(getProductData(),INDEX(getProductData(),,3)="red",""),2,1)` to filter my product data by the 3rd column if the `value = red`, then sort by the 2nd column of the resulting array

But I was hoping to do something like
`=SORT(filter_arr(getProductData(),3,"red"),2,1)` to do the same

Naturally I'm still just playing around to determine what I can pull off - maybe using `INDEX` is the way to go and I'm trying to reinvent the wheel

Comment: I would think about creating a class which provides the flexibility you want .  I would suggest that internal to the class you convert the array to a collection of collections using either Collection, ArrayList or Scripting.Dictionary as your collection object (whichever is the best fit).  Write methods or properties to expand/contract access individual items as required.

Comment: Just for some context, what is the purpose of this code; is it called from the worksheet as a UDF or from other vba code? What sort of data are you passing in, and is this just 1 step of a bigger process? Are you having performance issues? Update your question to include any of that sort of stuff if you can:)

Comment: I added some details of what my plans were for this function

Comment: Too short for a review, but VBA is slow and it's not too hard to make this work with spreadsheet formulae, but use LET or LAMBDA to avoid repeating the calculation: `=LET(array,getProductData(),FILTER(array,INDEX(array,,3)="red"))`. Or better (but requires beta channel): `FILTERIF = LAMBDA(array,filter_index,include_if,FILTER(array,INDEX(array,,filter_index) = include_if))` called like `=FILTERIF(getProductData(),3,"red")`

Comment: @Greedo Although I haven't used them, I believe that my answer would outperform `Let` and `Lambda`.  In any case, not every version of Excel supports them.

Comment: @TinMan well, only one way to verify that claim, although worksheet functions are not easy to profile (perhaps using evaluate). True, not everywhere but op doesn't state constraints and I think LET is becoming increasingly widely available.

Comment: @Greedo I would think that `Range("A1").Formula = Lambda` would automatically synchronously spill.  So applying it to a large data set would be timeable.  We would then have to time the assignment of values returned by my function.  I wish I had the time to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReDim Preserve` and `Transpose` are not free.  I use this pattern when I need to filter an array:

1. Declare a 1-D array (Indices) with the same number of rows as the 2D array
2. When a match is found add the matches index to the Indices array and increment the counter
3. If there is matching data, declare a 2-D array (Results) with the same dimensions of the Input array but a row count equal to the counter
4. Iterate over the indices in the Indices array and add the matching values to the Results
5. Return the Results
6. If there are no matches return an empty array

### Quick Filter

````
Public Function QuickFilter(input_arr As Variant, col_index As Long, filter_value As Variant) As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim Indices As Variant
    ReDim Indices(LBound(input_arr, 1) To UBound(input_arr, 1))
    Count = LBound(input_arr, 1) - 1
    For r = LBound(input_arr, 1) To UBound(input_arr, 1)
        If input_arr(r, col_index) = filter_value Then
            Count = Count + 1
            Indices(Count) = r
        End If
    Next
    
    Dim Results As Variant
    Dim c As Long
    Dim index As Long
    If Count >= LBound(input_arr, 1) Then
        ``` we want results to hold the entire row
        ReDim Results(LBound(input_arr, 1) To Count, LBound(input_arr, 2) To UBound(input_arr, 2))
        For r = LBound(input_arr, 1) To Count
            index = Indices(r)
            For c = LBound(input_arr, 2) To UBound(input_arr, 2)
                Results(r, c) = input_arr(index, c)
            Next
        Next
        QuickFilter = Results
    Else
        QuickFilter = Array()
    End If
End Function
````

Comment: I really examined this and it makes sense to me. 1. make `indices` w enough space in case every row hits 2. loop over `input_array`, storing the indices of `input_array` that hit, and recording `count` of hits. 3. make `results` w enough space to store `count` elements, 4. loop up to `count` populating `results` w rows from `input_array` corresponding to the values in `incides`. I'm still playing around with this but it feels like a good solution (or simple enough for me to understand).

Comment: I did a comparison using a dataset with 8000+ rows between a more elegant version of my function `filter_arr` and `QuickFilter` which showed `QuickFilter` was about 100 times faster. I guess the main point I have to accept is that looping over the data only once can look clean but `redim` is just such a speed bump that the code executes faster by replacing it with a combination of simpler operations.

Comment: @dactyrafficle The main thing to consider is `redim preserve` isn't free.  It is much faster to reserve enough room in memory once (create a buffer) and then trim off the fat in the end.  The same is true with strings.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment (and near terminal Covid-19 boredom) here is a starter for 10 for a class called 'FlexArray'.  The code compiles cleanly and doesn't generate any untoward Rubberduck code inspections but is otherwise untested.

Usage is

```
Dim myArray as FlexArray
set myArray = FlexArray.Make(inputarray)
```

Note the Rubberduck annotations for PredeclaredId and Exposed.  If you are unable to use the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin you will need to export the class to a text editor to set the relevant attributes.

```
'@PredeclaredId
'@Exposed
Option Explicit
' See https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/

Private Type State

    Data                    As ArrayList
    
End Type

Private s As State

Public Function Make(ByVal ipTable As Variant) As FlexArray

    With New FlexArray
    
        Set Make = .Self(ipTable)
    
    End With
    
End Function


Public Function Self(ByVal ipTable As Variant) As FlexArray

    Set s.Data = New ArrayList
    
    Dim myRow As Long
    For myRow = LBound(ipTable, 1) To UBound(ipTable, 1)

        s.Data.Add New ArrayList

        Dim myCol As Long
        For myCol = LBound(ipTable, 2) To UBound(ipTable, 2)
        
            s.Data.Item(myRow).Add myCol, ipTable(myRow, myCol)
            
        Next
        
    Next
    
    Set Self = Me
    
End Function
            
        
Public Property Get Item(ByVal ipRow As Long, ByVal ipCol As Long) As Variant

    Item = s.Data.Item(ipRow).Item(ipCol)
    
End Property

Public Property Let Item(ByVal ipRow As Long, ByVal ipCol As Long, ByVal ipValue As Variant)

    s.Data.Item(ipRow).Item(ipCol) = ipValue

End Property

Public Function GetArrayRC() As Variant

    Dim myTable As Variant
    ReDim myTable(0 To s.Data.Count - 1, 0 To s.Data.Item(0).Count - 1)
    
    Dim myRow As Long
    For myRow = LBound(myTable, 1) To UBound(myTable, 1)
    
        Dim myCol As Long
        For myCol = LBound(myTable, 2) To UBound(myTable, 2)
        
            myTable(myRow, myCol) = s.Data.Item(myRow).Item(myCol)
            
        Next
        
    Next
    
    GetArrayRC = myTable
    
End Function


Public Function GetArrayCR() As Variant
    
    Dim myTable As Variant
    ReDim myTable(0 To s.Data.Item(0).Count - 1, 0 To s.Data.Count - 1)

    Dim myRow As Long
    For myRow = LBound(myTable, 2) To UBound(myTable, 2)

        Dim myCol As Long
        For myCol = LBound(myTable, 1) To UBound(myTable, 1)
        
            myTable(myCol, myRow) = s.Data.Item(myCol).Item(myRow)
            
        Next
        
    Next
    
    GetArrayCR = myTable
    
End Function

Public Sub InsertRow(ByVal ipRow As Long)

    s.Data.Insert ipRow, New ArrayList
    
End Sub


Public Sub RemoveRow(ByVal ipRow As Long)

    s.Data.RemoveAt ipRow
    
End Sub


Public Sub InsertCol(ByVal ipCol As Long, Optional ByVal ipColArray As Variant)

    Dim myRow As Long
    For myRow = 0 To s.Data.Count - 1
    
        If myRow < UBound(ipColArray) Then
        
            s.Data.Item(myRow).Insert ipCol, ipColArray(myRow)
            
        Else
        
            s.Data.Item(myRow).Insert ipCol, Empty
            
        End If
        
    Next
 
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveCol(ByVal ipCol As Long, Optional ByVal ipColArray As Variant)

    Dim myRow As Long
    For myRow = 0 To s.Data.Count - 1
        
        s.Data.Item(myRow).RemoveAt ipCol
        
    Next
 
End Sub

Public Property Get Row(ByVal ipRow As Long) As Variant
    Row = s.Data.Item(ipRow).Clone
End Property

Public Property Let Row(ByVal ipRow As Long, ByVal ipRowArray As Variant)
    ' The .AddRange method cannot be used because ArrayList is a new object
    ' and expects an array that implements ICOllection
    ' VBA arrays do not implement ICOllection so the incoming array
    ' has to be added item by item
    
    Dim myRowLen As Long
    myRowLen = UBound(ipRowArray) - LBound(ipRowArray)
    
    Dim myCol As Long
    For myCol = 0 To s.Data.Item(ipRow).Count - 1
    
        If myCol <= myRowLen Then
        
            s.Data.Item(ipRow).Item(myCol) = ipRowArray(myCol)
            
        Else
        
            s.Data.Item(ipRow).Item(myCol) = Empty
            
        End If
    
    Next
    
End Property

Public Property Get Col(ByVal ipCol As Long) As Variant
    Dim myCol As ArrayList
    Set myCol = New ArrayList
    
    Dim myRow As Long
    For myRow = 0 To s.Data.Count - 1
    
        myCol.Add s.Data.Item(myRow).Item(ipCol)
    
    Next
    
    Col = myCol.Clone
    
End Property

Public Property Let Col(ByVal ipCol As Long, ByVal ipColArray As Variant)
    ' The .AddRange method cannot be used because ArrayList is a .Net object
    ' and expects an array that implements ICOllection
    ' VBA arrays do not implement ICOllection so the incoming array
    ' has to be added item by item
    
    Dim myColLen As Long
    myColLen = UBound(ipColArray) - LBound(ipColArray)
    
    Dim myRow As Long
    For myRow = 0 To s.Data.Count - 1
    
        If myRow <= myColLen Then
        
            s.Data.Item(myRow).Item(ipCol) = ipColArray(myRow)
            
        Else
        
            s.Data.Item(myRow).Item(ipCol) = Empty
            
        End If
    
    Next
    
End Property
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].